# how to get Possibility of all possible CRON patterns from the current timestamp?

Tags: python, node.js, cron

I want to find all possibilities of the cron patterns (* * * * * *) which would be possible from the current timeStamp. 
Maybe **40** are possible but I want a right way to implement an algorithm in Node.
So please suggest me if any NPM package is available for this. Or help me If you have any IDEAs regarding my issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are (effectively) an infinite number of cron patterns that can match a given timestamp....far more than 40.

Comment: Ya, Agreed with you. It's Not infinite but minimum **6!**. (Not including 'range[-] of day, month, year, time with division minute etc.)

I just want pattern possible with above six stars (* * * * * *) . That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is difficult to answer because it's not clear what you want to do with this information.

If you *exclude* ranges, divisions, and comma-separated lists, then you only have 2 valid values for each spot, meaning there are only 64 (2^6) possibilities. As an example, consider the current time is `Monday, Sep 10, 2018 08:33:55`:

```
- MINUTE can be                    33 or *
- HOUR can be                       8 or *
- DAY OF MONTH can be              10 or *
- MONTH can be                      9 or *
- DAY OF THE WEEK can be            1 or *
- YEAR (usually excluded) can be 2018 or *
```

This of course is an extreme lowball answer. If you allow any of these fields to use valid cron syntax (commas, dashes, H/X, etc.), this number will explode; in the minute field alone there would be thousands of valid ways to include the number 33.

Comment: Ya, agreed with you dude! I'm creating an algorithm which will give us the minimum possibility of cron patterns from the timestamp.
Thanks for your valuable answer.